# How do I add/get values from a 'child' directive in a ngForm?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

Having the following code:

```
<form #carForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="createCar(carForm)">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputCarName">Car Name</label>
          <input [(ngModel)]="name" name="name" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputPrice">Price</label>
          <input [(ngModel)]="price" name="price" type="number">
        </div>
        <select-inputs-brand></select-inputs-brand>
</form>
```

the `<select-inputs-brand>` "child" directive points to the following code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="brandSelect1">Select Brand:</label>
  <select multiple class="form-control" id="brandSelect2">
    <option>Fird</option>
    <option>GM</option>
    <option>Audi</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

> How can I get the options available in `<select-inputs-brand>`
>   directive in my `carForm` object?

In case of extra clarification needed, please let me know.

Thanks in advance,
Roger A L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `select-inputs-brand`'s typescript code you declare a member variable with the options:

```
class SelectInputsBrand {
    public options: string[]
    constructor() {
        this.options = ['Ford', 'GM', 'Audi']
    }
}
```

In the `html` of your directive you bind these options to the dropdown in the UI:

```
<select multiple class="form-control" id="brandSelect2">
    <option *ngFor="let o of options">{{ o }}</option>
</select>
```

In the typescript code of `carForm` you declare a member variable which will hold the instance of the directive:

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core'
import { SelectInputsBrand } from 'wherever/it/is/placed'

export class CarForm {
    @ViewChild('myDropdown') private myDropdown: SelectInputsBrand;

    someFunction() {
        let whatYouNeed = this.myDropdown.options <-- this will give you the options.
    }
}
```

In the html of your `carForm` you give the directive an ID:

```
<select-inputs-brand #myDropdown></select-inputs-brand>
```